# How do you make a timestamp from separate date and time columns in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp

I have a date column and a time column in Postgresql. I would like to combine the two columns into a timestamp column. For example, I want

```sql
date_col (timestamp)
-----------------------
2021-06-28 00:00:00.000
2021-10-11 00:00:00.000
2021-04-01 00:00:00.000

time_col (varchar)
-----------------------
'01:25:00'
'10:55:00'
'08:25:00'
```

to become

```sql
timestamp_col (timestamp)
-----------------------
2021-06-28 01:25:00
2021-10-11 10:55:00
2021-04-01 08:25:00
```

Is this possible without tediously doing

```sql
make_timestamp(date_part('year', date_col), date_part('month', date_col), date_part('day', date_col), date_part('hour', time_col), date_part('minute', time_col), date_part('second', time_col))
```

Comment: `select date_col + time_col::time as new_timestamp;` If `date_col` can have a time component other then `00:00:00.000` do as @a_horse_with_no_name suggests and use `date_col::date`

Comment: Storing a time value in a `varchar` was a big mistake to begin with. Why don't you merge those two columns into just one and drop the `time_col` column completely?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it looks like this is the case because with the application, users enter a date and time in separate fields/boxes.

Comment: That is what the OP is trying to achieve: 'I would like to combine the two columns into a timestamp column. .. to become timestamp_col'.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: my understanding is that scrollout is looking for a SELECT that returns both in a single column. Not to change the definition of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just cast the `timestamp` to a date and add the time (after casting *that* to a `time`):

```
select date_col::date + time_col::time as timestamp_col
from the_table;
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the types. With your help, I found that `date_col::date + time_col::time as timestamp_col` works.